# What was the third occasion when the Chicago PD fought supernatural opponents?

Tags: the-dresden-files

From *Small Favour*, chapter 17:

> "We've gone up against the supernatural three times", she [Murphy] said quietly.  "It's ended badly twice."
>
> We meaning the cops, of course.  I nodded.

One occasion is when the Loup Garou got loose in the police station and killed Ron Carmichael and a number of other people.

Another occasion (the one that *didn't* go badly) was the SI raid on Leonid Kravos, with Harry and Michael's assistance.

What was the third occasion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few different ways she could be interpreted.

The easiest is referring to Harry's first three cases.  Storm Front went well for them but ThreeEye didn't exactly expose the cops directly to the supernatural.  Fool Moon vastly less successful with the loup-garou rampage through the precinct, as you noted.  The raid on Leonid Kravos before Grave Peril went well, but the aftermath included a cop wrapped in spiritual barb wire, and Murphy being directly mind-raped by the Nightmare.  After that Murphy was clued in to the bigger picture in the next book, and kept the cops less involved.

She could also be referring to the events of Proven Guilty as the second bad event. Splattercon!!! was covered heavily by the cops and they could do jack squat about what happened, even with Murphy directly in on Dresden's work and other departments involved investigating and covering the show floor.  That had more public consequences and innocent lives lost on Murphy's watch, so that is how I would interpret it.  That would make the Fool Moon (bad loup-garou) and Grave Peril (good raid, limited consequences to select cops) the other big cases for SI, and the ThreeEye case could be just written off as business as usual.

Comment: The second Fetch attack in Proven Guilty sounds plausible, though as I remember it only Rawlins had any direct involvement.  I'll reread it and get back to you.

Comment: @Harry - the third attack, the one that Harry mostly redirected, was the one with the biggest police presence, because of the fatality at the second attack. The police still ended up with a panicked stampede, lots of injuries, and one corpse (possibly many more) left by the one fetch Harry had to take down personally.

Comment: I think I was conflating the second and third attacks.  If I'm now remembering rightly, Murphy and Rawlins (at least) were both there for the third one, which makes it an even more plausible candidate.  And Murphy was in charge of the investigation, is that right?  That's why she got demoted after disappearing for a day during the raid on Arctis Tor.

Comment: With homicide and FBI involved, "in charge" of the investigation becomes fuzzy to me. I think in charge enough to blame at least, so for discussion's sake, yup, she was.

Comment: I've reread chapter 25 of Proven Guilty, and it's a perfect fit.  At least one police officer was killed as well as several civilians.